# Failing SSH after disabling Root Login

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, rhel7, public-key-encryption

After generating the private and public key for a RHEL Client and storing the public key in the authorized_keys folder of the RHEL 7 Server, I disabled the Root Login in the Server by going to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and setting **PermitRootLogin** to no. After that I restarted the sshd service.

Now when I am trying to do ssh from client to server it says

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)

Why I am getting this message?

Comment: Where did you put the authorized key on the server? What user are you logging in as? what command used?

Comment: @shearn89 I have put the public key of client under authorized_key file of server in directory - /root/.ssh . I am logging in as root user. What do you mean by what command used? You are asking for which command?

Answer (score 5):

Your behavior is completely normal.
Change your
`PermitRootLogin no`
to a more conform to your needs
`PermitRootLogin without-password`

Be sure to have the right key at the right place (usually ~/.ssh/authorized_keys) with the good owner:group, and with the chmod 600 and 700 on ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and ~/.ssh.

Comment: Tried this. After this, now when I am doing ssh from client it is asking for password. Why's that? Password shouldn't be asked when doing ssh.